# Can't use cordova file transfer plug in on my device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I wrote an application using javascript/html and compiled into a phone app using cordova. The app is simple, it just uploads a selected picture from the phone to my server.

I tried it in some devices, but the one I need it to works, does not.
It is a LG X Power running android 6.0.1.

Thought it could be the android version but I ran android 6 on an emulator and it worked too, so I have no clue about what's going on.

Can anybody help me out? If you need the code, let me know so I can paste it here.

Code:

```
uploadImg: function(){
    var imageURI = JSON.parse(app.imgURI).filename;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = imageURI;
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://200.137.66.241:85/upload.php", win, fail, options);

    function win(r) {
        alert("Image has been uploaded!");
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to write to sd card maybe you're missing the autorizations.

Comment: Hey @QuickFix, thanks for answering. No I'm not trying to write anything, just select a picture and send it to my apache server. Any other idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: and is this picture on the sdcard? (there are autorizations for read and autorizations for write to the sd) you can check in the application settings page for your app in android if there are unchecked autorizations.

Comment: No, it's on internal storage as i don't have an sdcard in this phone

Comment: Code snippets are always helpful to better understand the problem. Also, just know that this plugin will become deprecated. https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

Comment: hey @johnborges, i just added some code, it's the upload function. The weird thing is that it works on all devices but the LG X Power, and this is the one I actually need this thing to work. Thanks in advance.